# Tensorflow object detection API evaluation stuck

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm using Tensorflow object detection API on my own data with faster_rcnn_resnet101 model. I'm training from scratch. Training part goes well, but evaluation part stuck from the start and never showed result. It looks like:

[image: evaluation stuck]

I tried using older version of api that I downloaded few months ago, on the same dataset. Everything worked. Is there something wrong with the current version of api, especially on evaluation part? Thank you for attention.

My configuration file looks like this:

```
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 10
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_resnet101'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0003
          schedule {
            step: 0
            learning_rate: .0003
          }
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00003
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000003
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  #fine_tune_checkpoint: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/model.ckpt"
  #from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  #num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/PATH/TO/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/PATH/TO/my_label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 2000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  #max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/PATH/TO/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/PATH/TO/my_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
  num_epochs: 1
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faster R-CNN object detector takes a little longer to evaluate (in comparison with YOLO or SSD) due to higher accuracy vs speed tradeoff. I recommend reducing the number of images to 5-10 to see if the evaluation script produces an output. As an additional check you can visualize the detected objects in tensorboard by adding the `num_visualizations` key to eval config:

```
eval_config: {
  num_examples: 10
  num_visualizations: 10
  min_score_threshold: 0.15
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 1
}
```

With the above config you should be able to see `images` tab in tensorboard with object detections. Notice that I also reduced the IoU threshold to 0.15 to allow detection of less confident boxes.